# Getting list of session IDs from State server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I get a list of active session IDs from State server in asp.net ?

Comment: @Waqas - I assume he means a Session State Server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to access State server. Microsoft already abstracted it through Session variable 
The easiest way is to use Session_Start, Session_End in Global class to add and remove session id

Comment: Session_End event not available for State server method, hence can not be used.